# question on Microsoft teams and azure ad connect

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Hello I am trying to retrieve the deleted Microsoft teams Team in order to restore that i saw a link where it shows to access the azure ad to restore the deleted office 365 group.

question 1: i have restored the office 365 group by going to exchange admin and is there any need i also need to restore it with power shell?

question 2: i cant see the Microsoft Team after restoring the o365 group
is there any wait time? for it to show up?

Question 3 : if you see the screenshot below i cant connect to the azure ad

even after installing the azure ad module it says modules does not exist .

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer and it take 24 hours to show up the deleted team

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2018/08/21/restore-deleted-teams-and-channels-from-microsoft-teams/